# Outlook Addin: How to actively release memory as suggested by Microsoft documentation?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

The outlook addin tries to retrieve Outlook.Exceptions correctly. I found the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-find-a-specific-appointment-in-a-recurring-appointment-series

There it says:
*[...] When you work with recurring appointment items, you should release any prior references, obtain new references to the recurring appointment item before you access or modify the item, and release these references as soon as you are finished and have saved the changes. This practice applies to the recurring AppointmentItem object, and any Exception or RecurrencePattern object. To release a reference in Visual Basic, set that existing object to Nothing. **In C#, explicitly release the memory for that object.**
[...]*

Now my question is how do I do that? The example on the referenced page does not explicitly release the memory?

Would it be sufficient to set appt to null?

Answer (score 1):

Setting to null is definitely not enough. In this case, additionally you have to force the garbage collector to swipe the heap as soon as possible. You do this correctly with calls to `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. Calling twice is safe, end ensures that cycles are definitely cleaned up too.

But I'd recommend using `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject` to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to `Nothing` in Visual Basic (`null` in C#) to release the reference to the object. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server (this number was increased in latest versions). If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time.

The `ReleaseComObject` method is used to explicitly control the lifetime of a COM object used from managed code. You should use this method to free the underlying COM object that holds references to resources in a timely manner or when objects must be freed in a specific order.

Every time a COM interface pointer enters the common language runtime (CLR), it is wrapped in an RCW.

The RCW has a reference count that is incremented every time a COM interface pointer is mapped to it. The `ReleaseComObject` method decrements the reference count of an RCW. When the reference count reaches zero, the runtime releases all its references on the unmanaged COM object, and throws a `System.NullReferenceException` if you attempt to use the object further. If the same COM interface is passed more than one time from unmanaged to managed code, the reference count on the wrapper is incremented every time, and calling ReleaseComObject returns the number of remaining references.

The `ReleaseComObject` method enables you to force an RCW reference count release so that it occurs precisely when you want it to. However, improper use of `ReleaseComObject` may cause your application to fail, or may cause an access violation.

Comment: Is it correct to say that at the end of every method where a method-local variable refers to an AppointmentItem one must actively call System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject?

Comment: No, it is not so actually... it depends on who retrieved or created an instance of the COM object. It is passed as a parameter, you shouldn't release it.

Answer (score 0):

Memory management in C# (CLR runtime) is automatic and employs a garbage collector.

Periodically, the garbage collector checks for unreachable objects to be reclaimed. This process is not deterministic unless you force it (but normally you shouldn't).

To have the memory of an object freed, you simply have to make it unreachable: this can happen in various combinations of setting to null all the references to the offending object or, letting go out of scope all of them (provided that you didn't assign it to fields of properties).